# How can I get some attributes from a website for scraping

Tags: python, html, web-scraping

I have an issue while trying to scrape a website. I have tried a couple of methods to get the restaurant_name, cuisine, address and star ratings but I keep getting the error `'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'` which shows that this `tr.find("a", class_="sc-dakcWe sc-liNYZW cPIBpC")` returns None for all the iterations.

I am using the zomato restaurant and an example url for this is https://www.zomato.com/kanpur/top-restaurants

python code

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

city = input("Enter your city: ")
url = "https://www.zomato.com/" + city + "/top-restaurants"
header = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.77 Safari/537.36"}
response = requests.get(url, headers=header)

html = response.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
print(soup.title.text)

top_rest = soup.find("div", class_="bke1zw-0 cMipmx")
list_tr = top_rest.find_all("div", class_="bke1zw-1")

restaurants = []
address = []
cuisine = []
ratings = []

for tr in list_tr:
    restaurant_name = tr.find("a", class_="sc-dakcWe sc-liNYZW cPIBpC").text.replace("\n", " ")
    print(restaurant_name)
    print("\n")
    address_name = tr.find("a", class_="sc-hwNDZK sc-fAUOfn iNshJR").text.replace("\n", " ")
    cuisine_name = tr.find("a", class_="sc-hwNDZK sc-cbKXXB fBpaBs").text.replace("\n", " ")
    ratings_name = tr.find("p", class_="sc-1hez2tp-0 sc-jjgyjb bQGuFm").text.replace("\n", " ")
    
    restaurants.append(restaurant_name.strip())
    address.append(address_name.strip())
    cuisine.append(cuisine_name.strip())
    ratings.append(ratings_name.strip())

print(restaurants, address, cuisine, rating)
```

Comment: page is loading dynamically so you have to use `selenium`

Comment: Have you looked at the source code for this page (using View Source)?  The entire page is constructed on the fly with Javascript.  You'll need something like `selenium`.

Comment: @gaurav I only need to get the current data on the page. I don't want to go too complex using selenium.

Comment: @king_bibah     as @Tim said you can't get the data , reason for this `requests` only loading or getting basic html stuff rest of part is render by JavaScript dynamically so use `selenium` .it is easy and you can also scrape from it.

Comment: The data is not part of the page.  It isn't there.  If you haven't looked at the source in Chrome, then you haven't really done the background work you need to solve this problem.

Comment: @TimRoberts I'm really not sure this is the case. If you ran OP's code, you would have seen that the GET request returns significant data. If you disable JavaScript, you'll see that while some of the material is not loaded, much of it is, enough to get what OP needs. I understand where you're coming from though, the source code is definitely empty. However, I think the data is generated dynamically serverside, not clientside.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how I was able to do it, not sure if it is the most efficient but it definitely works:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

city = input("Enter your city: ")
url = "https://www.zomato.com/" + city + "/top-restaurants"
header = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.77 Safari/537.36"}
response = requests.get(url, headers=header)

html = response.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
print(soup.title.text)

top_rest = soup.find("div", class_="bke1zw-0 cMipmx")

restaurants = []

restaurant_divs = top_rest.select("div > section > div")

for rdiv in restaurant_divs:
    name = rdiv.find("a", recursive=False).text.strip()
    rating_div, address_div, cuisine_div = rdiv.find_all("div", recursive=False)
    ratings = re.findall(r"([\d\.]+)\(([\d,]+)\)", rating_div.text)
    black_rating = (float(ratings[0][0]), int(ratings[0][1].replace(',', ''))) if ratings else (None, None)
    red_rating = (float(ratings[1][0]), int(ratings[1][1].replace(',', ''))) if len(ratings) > 1 else (None, None)
    restaurants.append({"name": name,
        "ratings": {
            "black": {
                "score": black_rating[0],
                "votes": black_rating[1]
                },
            "red": {
                "score": red_rating[0],
                "votes": red_rating[1]
                }
            },
        "location": address_div.text,
        "cuisine": cuisine_div.text
        })
```

Note that some unicode characters aren't displayed correctly, but that can be fixed later.

I also took some liberty and reformatted the response, please take a look:

```
Top Restaurants in Kanpur | Zomato
[
  {
    "name": "Grill Inn",
    "ratings": {
      "black": {
        "score": 3.4,
        "votes": 77
      },
      "red": {
        "score": 4.1,
        "votes": 1668
      }
    },
    "location": "Shyam Nagar",
    "cuisine": "Quick Bites\u00a0-\u00a0Italian"
  },
  {
    "name": "Shri Bhojnalaya Restaurant & Sweets",
    "ratings": {
      "black": {
        "score": 4.2,
        "votes": 492
      },
      "red": {
        "score": 3.8,
        "votes": 8151
      }
    },
    "location": "Vijay Nagar",
    "cuisine": "Quick Bites\u00a0-\u00a0North Indian,\u00a0Chinese,\u00a0Fast Fo
od,\u00a0Desserts"
  },
  {
    "name": "Barbeque Nation",
    "ratings": {
      "black": {
        "score": 4.9,
        "votes": 716
      },
      "red": {
        "score": 4.1,
        "votes": 275
      }
    },
    "location": "Mall Road",
    "cuisine": "Casual Dining\u00a0-\u00a0North Indian,\u00a0Mughlai,\u00a0Leban
ese,\u00a0Arabian,\u00a0Mediterranean"
  },
  {
    "name": "Kukkad at Nukkad",
    "ratings": {
      "black": {
        "score": 3.3,
        "votes": 272
      },
      "red": {
        "score": 4.2,
        "votes": 500
      }
    },
    "location": "Swaroop Nagar",
    "cuisine": "Casual Dining\u00a0-\u00a0Mughlai,\u00a0North Indian"
  },
  {
    "name": "Tadka The Food Hub",
    "ratings": {
      "black": {
        "score": 3.8,
        "votes": 181
      },
      "red": {
        "score": 3.9,
        "votes": 6594
      }
    },
    "location": "Kidwai Nagar Market",
    "cuisine": "Quick Bites\u00a0-\u00a0Chinese,\u00a0North Indian,\u00a0South I
ndian"
  },
  {
    "name": "Smile Pizza",
    "ratings": {
      "black": {
        "score": 3.8,
        "votes": 94
      },
      "red": {
        "score": 4.0,
        "votes": 3142
      }
    },
    "location": "Kidwai Nagar",
    "cuisine": "Quick Bites\u00a0-\u00a0Pizza,\u00a0Fast Food"
  },
  {
    "name": "Arabian Broost Chicken",
    "ratings": {
      "black": {
        "score": 4.3,
        "votes": 420
      },
      "red": {
        "score": 4.2,
        "votes": 7051
      }
    },
    "location": "Chamanganj",
    "cuisine": "Quick Bites\u00a0-\u00a0Arabian"
  },
  {
    "name": "Chachi Vaishno Dhaba",
    "ratings": {
      "black": {
        "score": 4.2,
        "votes": 346
      },
      "red": {
        "score": 3.9,
        "votes": 6354
      }
    },
    "location": "Nandlal Chawraha",
    "cuisine": "Dhaba\u00a0-\u00a0North Indian"
  },
  {
    "name": "Barra House",
    "ratings": {
      "black": {
        "score": 4.2,
        "votes": 274
      },
      "red": {
        "score": 3.8,
        "votes": 6233
      }
    },
    "location": "Kanpur Cantt",
    "cuisine": "Quick Bites\u00a0-\u00a0North Indian,\u00a0Mughlai"
  },
  {
    "name": "Pashtun's",
    "ratings": {
      "black": {
        "score": 3.7,
        "votes": 28
      },
      "red": {
        "score": 3.9,
        "votes": 254
      }
    },
    "location": "Swaroop Nagar",
    "cuisine": "Quick Bites\u00a0-\u00a0Kebab,\u00a0North Indian"
  },
  {
    "name": "Agra Vala Sweets",
    "ratings": {
      "black": {
        "score": 4.0,
        "votes": 174
      },
      "red": {
        "score": 4.4,
        "votes": 5495
      }
    },
    "location": "Ashok Nagar",
    "cuisine": "Quick Bites,\u00a0Sweet Shop\u00a0-\u00a0Street Food,\u00a0Mitha
i"
  },
  {
    "name": "Al-Baik.Com",
    "ratings": {
      "black": {
        "score": 3.9,
        "votes": 77
      },
      "red": {
        "score": null,
        "votes": null
      }
    },
    "location": "Shyam Nagar",
    "cuisine": "Quick Bites\u00a0-\u00a0Fast Food"
  },
  {
    "name": "The Imperial Cord",
    "ratings": {
      "black": {
        "score": 3.8,
        "votes": 2519
      },
      "red": {
        "score": null,
        "votes": null
      }
    },
    "location": "Kakadeo",
    "cuisine": "Quick Bites\u00a0-\u00a0Fast Food,\u00a0North Indian"
  },
  {
    "name": "Google Fast Food",
    "ratings": {
      "black": {
        "score": 4.1,
        "votes": 144
      },
      "red": {
        "score": 4.2,
        "votes": 2006
      }
    },
    "location": "Nandlal Chawraha",
    "cuisine": "Quick Bites\u00a0-\u00a0Fast Food,\u00a0Chinese,\u00a0North Indi
an"
  },
  {
    "name": "Baba Foods",
    "ratings": {
      "black": {
        "score": 4.5,
        "votes": 1229
      },
      "red": {
        "score": 4.2,
        "votes": 2668
      }
    },
    "location": "Swaroop Nagar",
    "cuisine": "Quick Bites\u00a0-\u00a0North Indian,\u00a0Biryani,\u00a0Beverag
es,\u00a0Desserts"
  },
  {
    "name": "R S Bhojnalaya",
    "ratings": {
      "black": {
        "score": 4.2,
        "votes": 530
      },
      "red": {
        "score": null,
        "votes": null
      }
    },
    "location": "Kakadeo",
    "cuisine": "Bhojanalya\u00a0-\u00a0North Indian"
  },
  {
    "name": "Kerela Cafe",
    "ratings": {
      "black": {
        "score": 4.1,
        "votes": 299
      },
      "red": {
        "score": 3.9,
        "votes": 4191
      }
    },
    "location": "IIT Kanpur",
    "cuisine": "Quick Bites\u00a0-\u00a0South Indian"
  },
  {
    "name": "Mama Hotel",
    "ratings": {
      "black": {
        "score": 4.1,
        "votes": 364
      },
      "red": {
        "score": null,
        "votes": null
      }
    },
    "location": "Swaroop Nagar",
    "cuisine": "Quick Bites\u00a0-\u00a0North Indian,\u00a0Beverages"
  },
  {
    "name": "Gyan Vaishnav",
    "ratings": {
      "black": {
        "score": 4.6,
        "votes": 927
      },
      "red": {
        "score": null,
        "votes": null
      }
    },
    "location": "Ashok Nagar",
    "cuisine": "Casual Dining\u00a0-\u00a0North Indian"
  },
  {
    "name": "New Pizza Yum",
    "ratings": {
      "black": {
        "score": 3.8,
        "votes": 201
      },
      "red": {
        "score": 4.1,
        "votes": 2624
      }
    },
    "location": "Kakadeo",
    "cuisine": "Quick Bites\u00a0-\u00a0Pizza"
  },
  {
    "name": "Offline Cafe",
    "ratings": {
      "black": {
        "score": 4.1,
        "votes": 624
      },
      "red": {
        "score": 3.7,
        "votes": 1995
      }
    },
    "location": "Tilak Nagar",
    "cuisine": "Caf\u00e9\u00a0-\u00a0Cafe,\u00a0North Indian,\u00a0Fast Food"
  },
  {
    "name": "The Chocolate Room",
    "ratings": {
      "black": {
        "score": 4.0,
        "votes": 463
      },
      "red": {
        "score": 4.0,
        "votes": 5868
      }
    },
    "location": "Swaroop Nagar",
    "cuisine": "Caf\u00e9,\u00a0Dessert Parlor\u00a0-\u00a0Cafe,\u00a0Desserts"
  },
  {
    "name": "Mocha",
    "ratings": {
      "black": {
        "score": 4.7,
        "votes": 1146
      },
      "red": {
        "score": 4.0,
        "votes": 1138
      }
    },
    "location": "Mall Road",
    "cuisine": "Caf\u00e9,\u00a0Casual Dining\u00a0-\u00a0Cafe"
  }
]
```

Comment: how can i enable utf-8 encodings for this, so that i get the special characters displayed properly.

Comment: Also, this seems like tuple unpacking that you did here, rating_div, address_div, cuisine_div = rdiv.find_all("div", recursive=False). I thought the ".find_all" method returns a list and not a tuple. I am a little bit confused here. could you please explain better.